# Infinity/-infinity for skip list insertion with unknown type?

Tags: insert, max, default, min, skip-lists

I'm implementing a skip list like:

```
template<typename Key, typename Value> class SkipList {...}
```

In explanations I've seen online, the head and tail of the skip lists have infinity/negative infinity keys, but they're all used with number keys.

I can assume that `<` and `==` operators are available for keys, so I don't have to worry about `string < string`

But, how do I find a value for the smallest/largest type to have as head/tail pointers? Is there something like `INT_MAX` or `INT_MIN` but for any type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two properties `private SkipListItem<K, E> negInfinity;` and `private SkipListItem<K, E> posInfinity;` and compare the SkipListItems with them later on.

Here is how I went about it:

```
private SkipListItem<K, E> negInfinity;
private SkipListItem<K, E> posInfinity;

public SkipListDictionary(K[] keys, E[] elements) {

    this.randomGenerator = new Random();
    this.negInfinity = new SkipListItem<K, E>();
    this.posInfinity = new SkipListItem<K, E>();

    this.constructSkipList(keys, elements);
}
```

And then later on...:

```
private SkipListItem<K, E> searchKey(K key) {

    SkipListItem<K, E> currentElement = this.lastListStart;

    while(currentElement.lower != null) {

        currentElement = currentElement.lower;

        while(currentElement.next != null && currentElement.next.getItem() != posInfinity &&
                currentElement.next.getKey().compareTo(key) < 1) {

            currentElement = currentElement.next;
        }
    }

    return  currentElement;
}
```

P.S.: I used a property `referenceItem` for the upper lists to reference a lower `SkipListItem` for easier construction, that's why there is this `getItem` which returns a `SkipListItem`. I don't however think this is the best way to solve it, it's just what I went for.